# Animation with python NLA tracks failed

Tags: python, animation, nla-editor

I am trying to follow Blender sushi tutorial about animation with python, The video link is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWX0e1tyV5w

The text version here http://blendersushi.blogspot.fi/2013/05/python-nla-non-linear-animation-with.html

Every times I run the script, it fails on the line

```
if NEWTRACK in rig.animation_data.nla_tracks:
```

Comment: Can you post the error message printed to the console window https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/console_window.html

Comment: The error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nla_tracks'

Comment: ie the "rig" material has no animation data.

Comment: The thing is i don't have a rig in the file, Please watch the video is just about 5 min

Comment: I did some digging this question could more like does Blender python still uses rig.animation_data.nla_tracks with object?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of scripts in one `rig = bpy.context.active_object` in the other `rig = bpy.context.active_object.data.materials[0]`  I'm assuming you are on the first as the second (materials one) creates the animation_data.

The objects are taken from the `context.selected_objects` collection, by  name, then sorted, then iterated and made active.

However if you have an object selected that doesn't have any animation_data, ie has no action with keyframes nor a driver, then the script will fail because `obj.animation_data is None` and as the error says

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nla_tracks'

One fix would be to replace

```
objs = bpy.context.selected_objects
```

with

```
objs = [o for o in bpy.context.selected_object if o.animation_data]
```

or go straight to names

```
names = [o.name for o in bpy.context.selected_objects
            if o.animation_data]
```

to make sure each object, from selected_objects collection, has animation data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes it does solve the first problem and then i got an other one. But i don't know should i post an other question or should i just ask for the working script if you did make it work?
For the problem i get an error. RuntimeError: Error: unable to add strip (the track does not have any space to accommodate this new strip) Note that i m beginner in python or should i say bpy